# How do I use the between() after find()

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to get data by condition "between 'A' and 'B'"

But when I do like this

```
$query= $this->Tables->find('all',
    [
        'fields' => ['id','name']
    ]
)->between('id',10,20);
```

Cake will tell me

```
Unknown method "between"
```

How should I do?